# Reshape table: year vs monthly data

Tags: r, time-series, reshape

Making the dataframe

```
a <- c(1981,11.663480,12.580290,11.728730,10.403690,8.065430,7.498169,9.858521,   
   10.503750,12.837550,13.322750,12.120450,13.466980)
b <- c(1982,13.250670,13.158510,13.805300,13.768520,12.035980,9.121552,11.130580,   
   12.353730,12.448520,12.690670,12.369690,13.099700)
Data <- as.data.frame(t(a))
Data[2,]<- t(b)
```

The first column is for the year and the rest is for every month.
I want to reshape the data frame to 2 columns, first column for dates and the second for values. Obviously, the real table is for 40 years.

something like this

```
    dates    value
[1] 1981/01  11.663
[2] 1981/02  12.58
```

I use this to reshape:

```
library(reshape)
md <- melt(Data, id=(c("V1")))
```

Now I can re-order, in the data frame "md", the column corresponding to years start in 1981. I try to use `cast` to extract, but can't do it.

Comment: What is your expected output from `md`?  It is a 3 column dataset.  Why do you need `cast` again as it is the long format

Comment: every month of the corresponding year whit the value, starting: 01/1981 - 11.63

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `paste`ing the sequence of rows with the 'V1' column, do an `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
md %>% 
  group_by(V1) %>% 
  mutate(dates = sprintf('%d/%02d', V1, row_number()), value) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-V1, -variable) %>%
  arrange(dates)
```